# the css in my django project is not working

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

Please help me out.
I don't get any errors in my css file or in finding it, but still the style i would like is not shown.

my css file

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: deeppink !important;
}
```

my html page

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '../static/css/style.css' %}">


{% block content%}
<h1>All synonymes will be shown here</h1>

<form method=POST action="{% url 'add-vocabulair' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="search" placeholder="valt onder" aria-label="Search" name="onder" value={{key}}><br/>
        <input type="search" placeholder="woord" aria-label="Search" name="woord"><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{{woord}} <br/>
{{onder}}

{% endblock %}}
```

what can i do to make the style appear?

Comment: If you set the  `STATIC_ROOT` properly, you don't need to pass a relative path. Try: `href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"`

Answer (score 0):

First you check that your static folder is inside the app or it is outside, if it is outside then add one thing inside the settings.

`settings.py`:

```py
import os

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get started, check settings.py file : STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT settings.
You must have a Static directory at the root of the layout.
If everything is configured correctly, it should look like this.

```
href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"
```

In settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"))
```

P.S - Dont forgen about Nginx static configs (if you work in production server)